# template<typename T...>func(T&&..arg) and template<typename TT, typename... T>func(T&&..args); why do l-vals go to 2nd and r-vals not compile?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

## Problem Statement

The problem is as follows ([godbolt of the problem](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAArAAcpAAOqAqETgwe3r566ZmOAqHhUSyx8VwJtpj2xQxCBEzEBLk%2BfoF2mA7ZTS0EpZExcYkpCs2t7flctpODYcMVo9UAlLaoXsTI7Bzm/mHI3lgA1Cb%2BbhPEYcAA%2BgBueJgA7ufYJhoAgvuHx5hnFy8jlohAAnm8Pt8zAcGEcvKdzm4nFdMKwIV8frC/gC3GJgCRCAgWOioTC4QiLvcekRiCTMeT/oiQRM6dDfvDGRcWExUqyydjEVcbnz2RS3FQvLCGmIRViOTigXQwbKGTiCKDUphbgRiExCAo6RijZ8jkwFAoTgBZUEAeWi2khJgA7FYvqlrvcmAR2JCTn6ThN0CAQEKjCd0LdmGxzq7PqkvNEQcgQL7/YHg6HgCco5gIKsTmgGBMzi6TsRMAQtgxw5HWJgYyWACIA2P%2Bq22%2B0QdMhnU3bN1/MgGs5iA51apv3O1v%2B52NmOOp1z/yxyFXLwOdtuAzmhfTv1MIGocwANhOqE1uppJgSVgSjYgheL1rtDrMp5YHe046%2BbanE7bAYEEGKCbAQOKIicH4vgAdCO%2BaIhB3auLQ87GgB/rlpWxDVgAVAQCB4Aay7/rOjo/v63osKkBjemqGqMHW0FMScAAqJJtgeRAnicEqwhAbFvieTHQScLTAAo36fL%2BLr/m23ZoEC4EXGcZhmAAYngxAsgkbgMOYZioVJ6GAcBVIOCQiLPvabwBpgwBsIIFrnM2U7dvwxDPC06CImx/jYBAYkScJpHEeR6HuScD4CMWnFHm%2Btn2YwYFDkoiWOZJxklnumUnPhhEALRvOecRehZN7XveqUOQQ46hUZ6GkWFAGYVWJx4QRRHZY13xNZR1FepybjqpqOasSxpC5fRObCax7H%2BrF3G8cg/EnkJzGBRlM4yU1clAcGClgQhyn6UIPQCN5Ol6aphmZd2ZlXhcLG%2BdgCXVU5/guS6bkkJ5xDeY9bwBcQ4mrMFi43cZEVRUWYELfFVVJScKV2W9m0Ndt9U5XlCiFX5xWXmVt6VSjSW1dl0lzjtGEVq17WERDk7gxi4N1WRnxhGB3JhHmu7/taW5mhaTCGf%2BAD0osnAASvlnreJgFoQEQqCiRUeDAF4mydSczwCGAHBgWgVF0JgaMnOLonQUtlmfoDVkOjJqnC9di6kHbf6O/ps5k2zbbm8EMtiF48v/rFZ72lJznti%2B7tmE7BksxYZxNaHqD2onkduw7ZjRJ7Cch5bkqmBcbt%2BRAqfaJ8E3lxY3tof6fsB3LokMOgZaN0H%2BdW8XNul%2BXldR9ZWc587ja1z13yLhw6y0JwCS8H4HBaKQqCcG41jWAGmzbIy0I8KQBCaFP6wANYgMeZjQRoZgaAAnBoCQ39C/iSJIN81DPHCSPPh/L5wvAKCADQ%2B9D7rDgLAGAiAQJG3oGQCgUVoGjFNEYbUxBJTH1IFgR4OwABqTxng2hGpwPeNBaDei0pQaIP9ohhBaKCIhvBqHMGIJ%2Bak9DSCG2qjaBgtA6GL14FgaIXhgC4loLQAB3B%2BGYG5EYcQfCMGaWpHgKk4il6YFUD0IEuwl4czqD/EE0RdTMI8FgNhvYWD0PWFQAw4lcEvAIYwNh/BBAiDEOwKQMhBCKBUOoORuhZgGCMCgdelh9B4GiAA2AOYQBUBYAQUgVJ4g6jQaAqJuojDy3uIEBJIAkkMGPqsdY54GjiPygAdTELQE4ZS1E6iYFUm0ZgqmBmcqYSw1guBOl4KgBJ1wsARLzLUeo2QXAt2mH4WYIRFjlEqAUDIWQBBjNmUUbIQxpkrEGYogQ/QpieA6HobovQtnzFWSMKocwBiLNmBMAYJzlhVHWAoLeOwJDT1nt/ORK8OAnFUEkY8%2BVjySALAErMitUF5PzBAXAhASAqX8FwVYvAD58IKaQBAqIsDxAGafSQx5oKvzME6J0ql/DHgfgkJ079OBf1IOY6El9/AJGhBoBlTKWVmFIAvJenz/6AOAci0gYDIGgXjHEuBmB8A0jwEGWYTjhCiHEO42VXi1A/z8aQZ4upUgWP0G8jlP9Pk2iBCKs8VBvm/P%2BYCpBILcn5Mih4BBxBYXwsRSA9YaKmAYsoK8z%2BvBzFOlxTfAF/rA2SGDUGvVHy/62F5UirQKLT7%2BCdNBG%2BTo7430kBof1pKEj3x1Rwfw7yuVRtjUfPNZhC1dOLa6%2BJcRMjOEkEAA%3D%3D)).

We're given a simple class and a struct class with two function templates.

```cpp
class MyObj
{
private:
    std::string d_name;
public:
    std::string name() const { return d_name; } ;
    MyObj(std::string name) : d_name(name)
    {
    };
};

struct MyClass
{
    auto& operator[](const MyObj& myObj)
    {
        std::cout << myObj.name() << std::endl;

        return *this;
    }

    template <typename... T>
    auto& func(T&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "First\n";
        std::vector<MyObj> segments = {std::forward<T>(args)...};
        for (const auto& segment : segments)
        {
            this->operator[](segment);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename TT, typename... T>
    auto& func(T&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "Second\n";
        std::vector<TT> segments = {std::forward<T>(args)...};
        for (const auto& segment : segments)
        {
            this->operator[](segment);
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

#### Case 1

Now, if we try to call `func` with l-values, the second function template is applied:

```cpp
auto objA = MyObj{"a"}; 
auto objB = MyObj{"b"};
a.func<MyObj>(objA, objB); // "Second" is printed
```

#### Case 2

However, if we try to call `func` with r-values, the compiler finds the call to `func` ambiguous:

```cpp
a.func<MyObj>(MyObj{"a"},MyObj{"a"}); // call to member function 'func' is ambiguous
```

Specifically, the compiler says:

```
x86-64 clang (trunk)
x86-64 clang (trunk)
-Wall -Wextra -O2 -std=c++17
123
<Compilation failed>

# For more information see the output window
x86-64 clang (trunk) - cached
<source>:69:7: error: call to member function 'func' is ambiguous
   69 |     a.func<MyObj>(MyObj{"a"},MyObj{"a"});
      |     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:39:11: note: candidate function [with T = <MyObj, MyObj>]
   39 |     auto& func(T&&... args)
      |           ^
<source>:51:11: note: candidate function [with TT = MyObj, T = <MyObj, MyObj>]
   51 |     auto& func(T&&... args)
```

#### Case 3

Furthermore, if we call `func` with a mixture of l-values and r-values, there's no ambiguity and the second function is chosen.

```
a.func<MyObj>(objA, MyObj{"b"});
```

From CPPInsights, in the third case, we get `[TT = MyObj, T = <MyObj&, MyObj>]`, which doesn't help me crack it.

## Question

The ambiguity errors, in the second case, make sense, *but why is the first call with the l-values not ambiguous*? Is it because we cannot have `[T = <MyObj&, MyObj&>]` if the signature is `T&&...`, but having `[TT = MyObj&, T = <MyObj&, MyObj&>]` can '*override*' it?

**Edit**:

I just want to say thank you to both of you @TedLyngmo and @BrianBi. Both of your answers helped me resolve my mystery and I wish I can accept both. Since I have to pick, I'll be going with Brian's one as it gave me more background that will be useful for my future questions.

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of putting the parameter pack in a vector and then calling `operator[]` in 
 a loop you could just do`(..., (*this)[args]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Call this overload 1
template <typename... T>
auto& func(T&&... args)

// Call this overload 2
template <typename TT, typename... T>
auto& func(T&&... args)
```

When you write `a.func<MyObj>(...)`, the compiler tries to interpret the call as a call to overload 1 and as a call to overload 2. If substitution or deduction fails for either overload, or if either overload is not viable, the other one wins by default. If both overloads end up viable, then overload resolution has to be applied to determine which one is called.

When the compiler tries to interpret it as a call to overload 1, it takes the explicitly specified `MyObj` template argument as the first element of the pack `T`, and then it tries to deduce the remaining elements of `T`. In other words, the first type in the pack `T` is `MyObj`, and the remaining types in `T` are to be deduced. But that would mean that the first function parameter has type `MyObj&&`, which can't bind to an lvalue of type `MyObj`. So when the first function argument is an lvalue, overload 1 is not viable, and overload 2 gets selected instead.

Answer (score 1):

> why is the first call with the l-values not ambiguous?

It's because the first `func` does not match at all. Since you've specified `T` to be `MyObj`, it's equivalent to:

```cpp
auto& func(MyObj&& a0, MyObj& a1);
```

and a call with

```cpp
a.func(objA, objB);
```

and you can't bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue.

In the matching `func`, `TT` goes unused so there's no problem there since `T&&...` are forwarding references.

Comment: Wouldn't the first overload actually be `auto& func(MyObj&& a0, MyObj& a1);`? 
Since by specialising using only `<MyObj>` we're saying the first argument is of type `MyObj` (an r-value type), please deduce the other arguments, and the other argument is given as an l-value. Either way of course, the first overload is rejected.

Comment: @ysoudan Yes, silly typo. Fixed.